# Complicated Declaration expression qustion

Tags: c

i have this expression    int *(*foo())[30]

> is foo a function (which receive no arguments) and returns a pointer to an array (size 30) of pointers of integers ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Try using the program "cdecl" for complex expressions.  Here is what it says:  cdecl> explain int *(*foo())[30]
declare foo as function returning pointer to array 30 of pointer to int

Comment: @JohnBode No, this isn't correct in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can decode declaration in reverse order of normal evaluation of expression.

Normal evaluation order:

1. `foo`
2. `foo()`
3. `*foo()`
4. `(*foo())[30]`
5. `*(*foo())[30]`

So this declaration is:

1. `*(*foo())[30]`: **a pointer**
2. `(*foo())[30]`: **array of** pointers
3. `*foo()`: **a pointer to** array of pointers
4. `foo()`: **function that returns a** pointer to array of pointers
5. `foo`

So this declaration means "a function `foo` that returns a pointer to array of pointers to `int`".

The point in which you are wrong is that the number of arguments of `foo` isn't specified here, so its number of arguments need not be zero.